# Open new window from next tkinter file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two .py file with each window in each file. I  need to navigate from one file to another or window to window. How do I do using button?

Comment: do you want to open new file in same window or just want to open next py file

Comment: I want to open window from next py file using button in that current file.

Comment: have you tried first google page ? https://gist.github.com/shopuz/1f68ee2907c3a273221b

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess here

Example :let file containing next window to be opened be 2.py

```
tn=Button(root,command=open)#root is the first windowname
tn.pack()
def open():
   from subprocess import call
   call(["python3 2.py"])
```

Similarly if you want to close current window,you can use

```
windowname.destroy()
```

So by combining both it can give the effect you need that is opening other py by clicking button in first and closing first.(only incase you do not need first window again with data it had earlier)

Example:

```
tn=Button(root,command=equal)#root is the first windowname
tn.pack()
def open():
   root.destroy()
   from subprocess import call
   call(["python3 2.py"])
```